# Grabbing innerHTML into a variable

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to grab the text in a p tag into a variable. The p tag is called #musCardImageTitle and is a description of the background image on that page. However, it's not working. I dont know why

```
var desc = document.getElementById("musCardImageTitle").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("sb_form_q").placeholder = desc

//the second line is putting that text into a searchbox as placeholder text
```

This is for the Bing homepage if it helps. I've included an image of what I'm trying to do if it helps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJeU8.jpg

I think this should be easy but for some reason I cant get it to work...

Comment: It works fine http://jsbin.com/diqayegepu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#musCardImageTitle');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

        //document.getElementById("sb_form_q").value = mutation.target.textContent ;
        document.getElementById("sb_form_q").placeholder = mutation.target.textContent;
        observer.disconnect();

    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

This example is on [MutationObserver doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit)

Comment: That one worked! But in the end it turned into real text and not placeholder. But I still appreciate it alot, thanks. Figured it would be easier than this though, man that seems needlessly complex. Thank u

Comment: Was able to change .value to .placeholder and it's as I intended . Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var desc = document.getElementById("musCardImageTitle").value;
```

Comment: Nothing. It gived 'undefined'.